# How to animate response "viber bot is typing" ? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, chatbot, viber, viber-bot

I want to give a more realistic experience to user by showing the text "**Bot is typing**" under chatbox, before viber bot sends the message (even simulated with a delay).

It is already implemented by viber but i could'n find any callback for that. Also known as **Typing Receipts** or **Typing Indicator**

Your help will be appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: `console.log("Bot is typing")`?

Comment: After start a conversation with a viber user, while is typing a reply to you, a small message appears under the chatbox saying "user X is typing". I'm trying to achieve this functionality with a bot. Before bot reply to user, to show this message... Definitely not a console.log but a reaction to viber user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not available for Viber Bots.

I saw similar functionality for Telegram and others, but not for Viber Bot API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed Telegram has this callback, i hope viber will extend its API.

Comment: @GeorgeGotsidis also hope so. Currently, when possible I'm sending separate messages like `Got that, one moment...` or `Processing...` or `Loading...`